# How to check if Resttemplate gets error?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, error-handling

How can I check if I get an error with `RestTemplate` in my `SpringBootApplication` properly?
I managed to create an `ResponseErrorHandler` but am not sure how to handle that error in my code. So I want to print an error message if an error occured and else process the response if everything is ok. How can I do that?

ErrorHandler:

```
public class MyErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    private boolean error;
    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        error = false;
        if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY) {
            error = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + response.getStatusCode() + ": " /*Can I print my errormessage here?*/);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return error;
    }
```

Getting Data:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        headers.add("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        HttpEntity<String> httpRequest = new HttpEntity<String>(request, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        String response = (String) restTemplate.postForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8081/post", httpRequest, String.class);

        /*If error occured, print errormessage, else do something*/
```

Server:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
    ResponseEntity add(@RequestBody String string) {

        if(acceptServerRequest)
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Post recieved: " + string);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity("Error!", HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like this

```
 String response = (String) restTemplate.postForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8081/post", httpRequest, String.class);
```

You can do like this

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = (String) restTemplate.postForEntity("http://127.0.0.1:8081/post", httpRequest, String.class);
```

With this response object you can get status doing `response.getStatus()` which retuns an object of type `HttpStatus` which has various utility methods like

```
is2xxSuccessful()
is4xxClientError()
```

Which can be used to get the status's in general